# Set form attributes on angular.ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular-ui

I have a form in my modal(angular ui). I need to set the attributes of the form from my controller.

my HomepageController:

```
var iframeModal = $modal.open({
     templateUrl: 'immdModal.html',
     controller: 'immdController',
     scope: $scope
});
iframeModal.result.then(function(selectedItem) {
  $scope.selected = selectedItem;
 }, function() {
});
```

And I have :

```
<div id="immdPwdResetFrame">
    <form id="myForm"></form>
    <iframe name="hidden_form_for_iframe"></iframe>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        document.forms["myForm"].submit();
    });
</script>
```

in my modal HTML(immdModal.HTML), and I have

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
});
```

in my immdController controller. But I get the error in console as : form is undefined.
How can I set the attributes of the form from the controller?

Comment: I am sorry, I should have provided : form.setAttribute("method", "post");

Comment: where do you declare your angular controller? i dont see either on the html or the javascript...also why use jquery ready event for one and angular ready event for another..also your form tag is for some reason self closing and has a closing tag, why? did you even finish asking your question there is a random "in my" at the end?

Comment: I am terribly sorry, for the mistakes. thats my modal's html and controller.

Comment: why are you using jQuery for any of this and not using angular? Approach is all wrong

Comment: controller is a very special term in angular...you need to use `ng-controller` and `app.controller` to be able to say you are using controllers

Comment: Oh! you mean that piece of code ... I have that code in my HomePage Controller, from where I open this angular modal. I have updated that code as above.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with all this?  BTW if you just want to put a "post" on the form, you can always set it in the <form> directly.  If you insist to do it programmatically and do weird tricks, go with a directive and do everything in the link function. (not very nice, but then, we have no idea what you are trying to do!!).. let me show you in an "answer"

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER: Trying to give a hacky workaround to the question's situation which seems strange: How to set the attribute on the form. This solution does exactly that using angular.

You could always define a directive for your form to perform DOM manipulations like:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

// Given that the myapp is properly referenced in the HTML (i.e. <html ng-app="myapp">) 
// this will execute on any element with an attribute named 'immd-modal-form'
app.directive("immdModalForm",function(){

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      element.attr("method", "post");

    }
  };
});
```

then

```
<form immd-modal-form></form>
```

Using angular.ready() / $(document).ready() in this fashion for a modal form is calling for trouble. These events are used upon the initial load of the page, not for modal initialization.

I believe that calling "submit()" on a form will probably kick you out of the page (redirect). There are many issues in your question.  You really need to tell us what you are trying to achieve. I am sure there is a much simpler way to do all of this!